# plotclick events in flot and enyo 1.0

Tags: flot, enyo

I am new to programming so please bear with me. I have an app built in enyo 1.0 with a working flot graph. I am trying to register click events on the graph so I can use that info elsewhere in the app. I have set clickable to true and I can see the data points highlight when I click on them so I know that part is working.  How do I get the series and data point I click on into enyo?  I am just having a difficult time figuring out from the different partial examples I can find what I need to put where.  I see reference to enyo.dispatcher.listen(document, “plotclick”); but I am not sure where that goes. Does anyone have a working  example they could share?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code.  Post what you have working so far.  Perhaps even create a jsFiddle...

Comment: Ok, here you go.
http://jsfiddle.net/UncleJ/cdMLt/2/
Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't look like `enyo.dispatcher.listen` is available in the version of enyo you are using.  I added a normal `jquery` handler and it works, but since I don't know anything about enyo, I'm not sure if it breaks the rest of the application.  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdMLt/3/

Comment: Thanks for your response,  on looking at the documentation again you are right about the dispatcher, looks like it should be more like: document.plotclick = enyo.dispatch;
I played around a bit more with the code and I can get it to alert the data I need but I am still not sure how to get it to call the “clickResponse”  function and set the content to “dataClicked” so it will show up below the graph. 
http://jsfiddle.net/UncleJ/cdMLt/5/